# Can't add a Segue between 2 ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I have two ViewControllers which both have a TableView. The first has a Bar Button Item (with segue) which leads to a new ViewController and the other a segue to a new viewController if tapped on the TableView and one to another ViewController via Bar Button Item. But now I can't perform a segue between these two ViewController but I once had one which I deleted but I have to add it again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Hey I'm trying to create an app for bookkeeping at my school with 3 tableviews. One where are your clubs/classes are ,than one with all the members of the club/class and all the transactions which the member did for example he bought a book. But now I can't  add a segue between the Tableview from the "ClubViewController" and the "MemberViewController" I also implemented a Tabbar because it didn't work without it.

Comment: Is there a method with which I can add a segue between two tableViews?

Comment: I don't have any code yet I just can't do a segue between them.

Comment: @TheClubApp Are your TableView's in their own controllers? If so, are you using storyboards? If you are, are your storyboard viewcontrollers set to use the `ViewController` files you've created?

Comment: @Jake yes they are both in a VC, do you mean in main.storyboard? If yes: Yes I do and they are connected to their ViewController files. Do I have to ctrl + drag from the tableview itself (thats what I'm doing) or from somewhere else?

Comment: Have you also connected the delegate and datasource from the table view to the view controller?

Comment: @jake yes I do but I found the problem which I could solce easily by ctrl+click on the prototype cell and drag to the new TableView. But thank you.